# Performance for loading pdf using PDFBox

Tags: java, performance, stream, inputstream, pdfbox

I am using the PDFBox (2.0.12) API to read and extract information from PDF files.
I have a performance issue that I couldn't figure out. Here is my problem:

I have a data set of 100 PDF files of about the same size, and with overall the same content in term of text and graphical elements. I noticed that the time for reading certain PDF files can be 10 times greater than the usual average time (it is the case for 8 files among 100). **Note** that I ran my tests on the whole data set at once, and also only on the files that take longer to load separately with the same results.

I tried to figure out the source of the long loading time, but I couldn't trace it further than the function **ProcessStream(...)** of the class **PDFStreamEngine**.

Could the problem be caused by something that take time to load in the pdfBox library side? Or could it be something related to InputStream used with the API?

**EDIT1**

For instance I wanna compare this two PDFs:

**pdf1**
[image: pdf1]

**pdf2**
[image: pdf2]

Here are some results for a loop reading the two files 5 times.
I even changed the order of reading both PDFs but got the same results.

```
|             |    PDF1     |     PDF2     |
|:----------- |------------:|:------------:|
| Reading time|  2077.67 ms | 128881.48 ms |
|  avg 5 run  |             |              |
|-------------|-------------|--------------|  
| size        |    9.6 Mo   |    924.5 kB  |
```

Here is a sample of the code that I use to read the files:

```
@Override
public void processFile() throws IOException, ExtractionException {

    TextComparator.chrono.start("Extraction " + key , 2 );
    log.info("Start Extraction " + key + "...");

    TextComparator.chrono.start("Reading raw " + key, 3);

    try {

        this.document = PDDocument.load(new File(path));
        setSuppressDuplicateOverlappingText(true);
        setShouldSeparateByBeads(true);
        setStartPage(0);
        setEndPage(document.getNumberOfPages());

        //Rotating the pdf page
        for (int i = 0; i < document.getNumberOfPages(); i++)
            document.getPage(i).setRotation(0);

        Writer dummy = new OutputStreamWriter(new ByteArrayOutputStream());   

        // Reading
        writeText(document, dummy);

        TextComparator.chrono.close("Reading raw " + key);

        TextComparator.chrono.start("Refining " + key, 3);


        log.info("---Number of extracted raw lines      : " + rawLines.size() );
        log.info("---Number of extracted cut lines      : " + nbCutLine );
        log.info("---Number of extracted raw paragraphs : " + paragraphs.size() );

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch (ExtractionException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ExtractionException(fileName, e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (document != null) {
            document.close();
        }
    }   
}
```

The above method is part of my own class that extends **PDFTextStripper** class of the PDFBox library. The core part of this method is the function
writeText(.,.) which is part of the PDFBox library. It calls internally some other functions, that I could trace back by overriding them and calling the
super function of the parent class. I went up until the function ProcessStream of the class **PDFStreamEngine** that I couldn't override since it is two class higher in hierarchy from my own class.

**Edit2**

Below are two plots summarizing my performance tests:

plot1: the loading time (logarithmic scale) for a bunch of pdf files (almost 220 files) as a function of the extraction order (order call 1 means that it's the first pdf to be loaded, 50 means it is the fiftiest loaded pdf and so on). The size is represented by the spectrum of color on the left.

[image]

plot2+3:
For two different pdf file I performed the extraction about 220 times.

[image: plot2]
[image]
I also noticed that when taking the same file and performing the extraction multiple time, the first extraction is 5 times slower than almost all of the following extractions.

Any hint on other parameters that may affect the extraction performance?

Many thanks,

Comment: Please share a sample PDF which loads slow for analysis.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr not sure why bit I guess it is because of the graphical elements. Anyway still it is 10x the size of the other one, and yet it takes 10x less time to read/load.

Comment: You can find the files here. 
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1KW5tVtF1gtcPNv2R7pIdDFMph8FhafT2?usp=sharing
I will have a look with PDFDebugger. Thanks for the hint

Comment: I ran the ExtractText command line utility and both files were done in 1 1/2 seconds. The big file is bigger because of different image compression (Flate instead of Jpeg). What speed do you get when using that tool?

Comment: 2 seconds for pdf1 and 12,9 seconds for the pdf2. For other files the time is usally between 1-2 seconds on average. Somehow, the performance drops randomly and I don't think it is file related ...

Comment: Another thing to try would be to update to the latest version of jdk. For 1.8, this is 191 or 192 (I used 192 to test). For jdk11, it is 11.0.1.

Comment: I ran the text extraction from both documents as unit tests, and the actual tests took less than a second each. So there seems to be something special about your setup...

Comment: Can you try a loop and see if the extraction time is about the same please?

Comment: 10 runs of plain text extraction from `284527_7605_CDM_PALET_MEDITERRANEEN_SURGELE_300G_FR_V1.pdf` take about 0.85s. 10 runs of plain text extraction from `284527_7605_CDM_PALET_MEDITERRANEEN_SURGELE_300G_FR_V2.pdf` take about 0.6s.

Comment: @mkl I just added two plots. I am really interested in your opinion.
Many thanks

Comment: If you again test those files which took so very long in your chart 1, do they still take so long?

Comment: *"I also noticed that when taking the same file and performing the extraction multiple time, the first extraction is 5 times slower than almost all of the following extractions."* that smells like IO caches in action.

Comment: @mkl I just added the plot. Is there a way to mitigate this IO cache issue?

Comment: As mentioned above, I don't see those vehement differences here. Thus, I'm afraid there is something special about your system giving rise to those results. Do you probably read the PDFs from some network storage and your network sometimes is very busy?

Comment: No, I have all the pdfs on local memory ... However, the pdf of plot 3 contains only graphical elements. This is the reason it takes much more time to process I think even if its size is not that big